# Just first alphabet is showing in the output.[char type]

Tags: c, string, printf, scanf

When I give the input then only first alphabet is showing.
I want to print the complete name which is I just entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name;
    char grades;
    int i;
    printf("Name of the Student:");
    scanf("%c",&name);
    printf("Name your Just entered is : %c",name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your edit made it a new question and invalidated existing answers so I rolled it back to the original. As a new user, please at least read the introductory [tour].

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the others - but add some error checking and ensure no buffer overruns i.e

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[101];

    printf("Name of the student:");
    if (scanf("%100s", &name) == 1) {
        printf("Name you just entered: %s\n", name);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("Unable to read name of student\n";
        return -1;
    }   
}
```

**EDIT**

As you have edited the question so that it does not have the same meaning as before I will leave my previous solution here.

But what you want is to use `fgets` - this allows for white space in the name

ie.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char name[100];
   printf("Name of student:");
   fflush(stdout);
   fgets(name, 100, stdin);
   printf("Students name is %s\n", name);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *can* interpret "the complete name" as 'including any spaces'. It may warrant a note on why `scanf` would not work anyway.

Comment: Good point - Added a note - hope the poster does not change the question again :-)

Answer (score 1):

`name` is a char and scanf will only catch one character when you use `%c`. You can use a char array to store the name instead :

```
char name[40];
/* edit the size for your need */
```

Also edit your scanf and printf to use a `%s`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `char name;` with `char name[100];`. This will define name as array of chars, because you handled with it as single character. 
For scanf replace it with `scanf("%s",&name[0]);`, and printf with `printf("Name your Just entered is : %s",name);`. %s means string, so it will scan whole string, not just single character. In scanf &name[0] points to beginning of array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `scanf` into an array, rather than into a single character:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[100];

    printf("Name of the student:");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("Name you just entered: %s\n", name);
}
```

Comment: Should add checked for the return value for `scanf` and ensure that it does not overrun the buffer

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store a array of characters(string) in a character. So only the first character is taken.To rectify this initialize the name as:

```
char name[40];
```

take input as :

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

and print as:

```
printf("name is %s",name);
```

Comment: Should add checked for the return value for scanf and ensure that it does not overrun the buffer

Answer (score 0):

You are reading (and printing) a single `char` using `%c`. If you want to handle stirngs, you should use a `char[]` and handle it with `%s`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()    
{

    char name[100]; /* Assume a name is no longer than 100 chars */      
    char grades;        
    int i;

    printf("Name of the Student: ");        
    scanf("%s",&name);

    printf("Name your Just entered is : %s",name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should add checked for the return value for scanf and ensure that it does not overrun the buffer.